# The drawn stm32 PCB is not recognized by stlink

Tags: stm32f1

Drew the PCB of stm32, DRC no problem.  After soldering on, after stlink connected to the board.  The power supply LED can also be displayed normally.  But keil shows NO target connected

What are the usual reasons why a drawn PCB cannot be recognized and the chip is not a problem. How to deal with these problems

Comment: Drawings do not connect to the debugger.

Comment: We will need more informations about your setup. Schematics or connection diagrams.
Also add what you tried to solve this issue already.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you all, it's because when the chip is soldered, there is a false solder, resulting in stlink can not be recognized to

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the microcontroller before soldering to the PCB? Are you sure that it was good? Please test the PCB. Maybe somewhere there is a short circuit or broken traces. You can use a multimeter. You can also make a [PCB tester](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Miniature_PCB_Tester_c2b226d2.html).